# template argument involving template parameters workaround

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I have the following partial specialization:

```
constexpr int NUM_ARGS = 3;

template <typename, typename, int> struct Dispatcher;

template <typename T, typename V>
struct Dispatcher<T, V, NUM_ARGS-1> {};
```

But now I need NUM_ARGS itself to be a template argument in Dispatcher.  But

```
template <typename, typename, int, int> struct Dispatcher;

template <typename T, typename V, int NUM_ARGS>
struct Dispatcher<T, V, NUM_ARGS, NUM_ARGS-1> { ...
```

is illegal.  So what is the workaround for this?

And response to Pradhan's solution, what would be the workaround for this illegal specialization?

```
template <int M, int N, typename... Args> struct Test;

template <int M, typename... Args>
struct Test<M, M-1, Args...> {};
```

where a default template parameter is not even permitted?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You mean you need to see more context?  Ok, I pasted it in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can't do arithmetic on the template parameters in the specialization arguments, you are allowed to do it in type arguments. Illustrating with a more minimal example than the one in the question :

```
template <int M, int N, typename Specialization = void>
class Test
{
    public:
    void foo(){cout << "Primary template." << endl;}
};

template <int M, int N>
class Test<M, N, enable_if_t<N==M-1>>
{
    public:
    void foo(){cout << "Specialization." << endl;}
};

int main()
{
    Test<5,10>().foo();
    Test<5,4>().foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
Primary template.
Specialization.
```

EDIT : In order to allow variadic arguments, we will have to keep `Specialization` as a type parameter without a default and use a template alias to make the interface cleaner.

```
template <int M, int N, typename Specialization, typename... Rest>
class Test
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<Specialization, void>::value, "Don't use Test directly. Use TestHelper instead.");
    public:
    void foo(){cout << "Primary template." << endl;}
};

template <int M, int N, typename... Rest>
class Test<M, N, enable_if_t<N==M-1>, Rest...>
{
    public:
    void foo(){cout << "Specialization." << endl;}
};

template <int M, int N, typename... Rest>
using TestHelper = Test<M, N, void, Rest...>;

int main()
{
    TestHelper<5,10, int, double, char>().foo();
    TestHelper<5,4, int, double, char>().foo();
    return 0;
}
```

[Coliru Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a162168baf89c51).

Comment: While at first glance your question seems to ask how to do arithmetic with non-type template parameters in a specialization, your MCVE shows no sign of you actually trying to do that - instead, it shows you trying to use a non-constant expression as a template non-type argument. If your question is really about the latter, please post a clarification.

Comment: My question is not about the latter.  It is about how to do arithmetic with non-type template parameters in a specialization.  So changing NUM_ARGS to constexpr does not solve the problem.  In fact NUM_ARGS is not to be global anymore.  It is to be moved inside the template arguments of Dispatcher.  I didn't do that in my question, because it is illegal is it is now.

Comment: Ok, this is a good start.  What if `typename Specialization = void` is not possible to begin with because there is a template pack, say,  `template <int M, int N, typename... Args> class Test;` at the end?  It would have to be removed and the class redesigned with something like `template <int M, int N, typename Pack> class Test;`, so that `typename Specialization = void` can be put at the end?

Comment: @prestokeys That is an interesting question - with function templates, the return type is a place where you can always throw in SFINAE. The trick in my example above is the usual trick for doing this with classes. At the moment, I can't think of a solution to your question.

Comment: @prestokeys Couldn't think of anything better than using a template alias to simulate default arguments.